# How to rectify rioxarray dimensions missing coordinates

Tags: python, rioxarray

I'm currently using the Python module rioxarray to clip an Xarray dataset based on a specific geometry to produce a latitude/longitude grid of coordinates. My data is below:

```
obs_dataset_full

xarray.Dataset

Dimensions:
Lat: 451 Lon: 350 lat: 450 lon: 350

Coordinates:
Lon
(Lon)
int64
0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 345 346 347 348 349
Lat
(Lat)
int64
0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 446 447 448 449 450
Longitude
(lon)
float64
-105.7 -105.7 ... -78.34 -78.26
Latitude
(lat)
float64
35.04 35.08 35.11 ... 51.52 51.56
spatial_ref
()
int64
0
Data variables:
precip_var
(lon, lat, Lon, Lat)
float64
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 nan

Attributes:
grid_mapping :
spatial_ref
```

Note: The Lon/Lat dimensions are irrelevant; I'm trying to utilize the lon/lat, which have the actual coordinates.

```
obs_dataset_full.rio.write_crs('EPSG:4326',inplace = True)
obs_dataset_cropped = obs_dataset_full.rio.clip(geometries=cropping_geometries, crs='EPSG:4326')
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
DimensionMissingCoordinateError: lon missing coordinates.
```

Both the `obs_dataset_full` dataset and the `precip_var` data array have the appropriate coordinates assigned to them, the lat/lon grid is filled with evenly spaced values, and the dimensions exist. Unfortunately, the rioxarray documentation page is not particularly clear as to what this exception entails.

Answer (score 1):

rioxarray expects the names of the coordinates and dimensions to be the same.

This should resolve your problem:

```py
obs_dataset_full = obs_dataset_full.rename(Longitude='lon', Latitude='lat')
```